# Speed up SVN backup

Tags: windows, batch, svn

The following [batch](/questions/tagged/batch) script runs on a Scheduled Task on Windows 7 with a quad core 2.5GHz and 16GB of DDR3.

It makes the [svn](/questions/tagged/svn) server unavailable for about 10 minutes, so it can produce a 500MB file, and this is only increasing.

How can I speed this up?

```
@echo off
mode con cols=33 lines=3 >nul
color 1F
if "%1"=="done" goto runtime
start "" /min %0 done
exit

:runtime
title Backing up SVN
echo.
echo.
echo  Backing up SVN... do NOT close!
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set bdate=%%c-%%b-%%a)
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set btime=%%a-%%b)
cd %temp%
rd /s /q svnbackup >nul 2>&1
md svnbackup
cd svnbackup
md certs
md conf
md uncommitted_db-pc
cd uncommitted_db-pc
net stop VisualSVNServer >nul 2>&1
svn status C:\SVN-EDGE>files.txt
for /F "tokens=1*" %%T in ('svn status C:\SVN-EDGE') do xcopy "%%U" ".\%%~pU" /F /H /K /X /Y /R /Q >nul 2>&1
svn status C:\INTERNAL>>files.txt
for /F "tokens=1*" %%T in ('svn status C:\INTERNAL') do xcopy "%%U" ".\%%~pU" /F /H /K /X /Y /R /Q >nul 2>&1
svn status C:\RESTRICTED>>files.txt
for /F "tokens=1*" %%T in ('svn status C:\RESTRICTED') do xcopy "%%U" ".\%%~pU" /F /H /K /X /Y /R /Q >nul 2>&1
cd ..
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 uncommitted_files.7z uncommitted_db-pc\* >nul 2>&1
rd /s /q uncommitted_db-pc >nul 2>&1
svnadmin dump --deltas --quiet S:/Customers > Customers.dump
svnadmin dump --deltas --quiet S:/Internal > Internal.dump
svnadmin dump --deltas --quiet S:/Restricted > Restricted.dump
net start VisualSVNServer >nul 2>&1
for %%I in (S:\authz S:\authz-windows S:\htpasswd C:\INTERNAL\SVN\Backup.bat) do copy %%I . >nul
copy "%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\certs\*" certs >nul
copy "%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\conf\*" conf >nul
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 %bdate%_%btime%.7z * >nul 2>&1
move 2*.7z C:\Users\DB\Dropbox\Backups\SVN >nul
cd ..
rd /s /q svnbackup >nul 2>&1
exit
```

Comment: For starters you could remove ***all*** unnecessary code.

Comment: @ProfPickle Such as? If you're referring to the first 12 lines, these take <1s to run. Otherwise I don't know what you're referring to.

Comment: Color, title, a majority of the `echo` commands... There's not a lot you can do to increase the speed of a batch file.

Comment: @ProfPickle I really don't mind waiting 100ms or however long it takes to run them lines... I'm looking at the bigger picture. I know 1 option is to use `svn hotcopy`, but I think it'd involve rewriting the majority of the script, and I don't know whether it would result in a speed increase? Related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33055/1563422

Comment: To be perfectly honest, the only thing that's going to increase the speed by any significant time is to choose another language. I know it's not the answer you're looking for but it's really a one way street here.

Comment: What's the time breakdown look like (more time 7zing or dumping?)? What are the svn repos like (tons of little files? a few huge files? etc)?

Comment: @Corbin I'll get a breakdown of what takes how long, but before I do, I don't suppose you know of a batch file performance profiling program? I tried the top hit on Google for `profile performance batch script`, but there's way too much noise for it to be useful (kernel/unrelated programs being profiled).

Comment: @DannyBeckett No idea :(. I rarely work with Windows batch scripts, but the few times I've had to figure out slow stuff, I just run things by hand. Basically what I'm trying to figure out is if you *can* speed this up. For example, if dumping the repo is taking 95% of the time, then there's not much you can do about that.

Comment: Quote from Max Bowsher FYI: "**Full-dump + bzip2 is smaller than delta-dump + bzip2** for at least some
kinds of data sets. Delta-dumps are **require more CPU-work to produce** *and consume*"

Comment: This isn't an answer, but a wacky suggestion, probably too wacky for your context: how about using git-svn and storing the backup as a git repository? You retain round-trip to svn, don't bring down the repo, don't have to re-read revs already backed up, and gain git's fast and efficient repository storage.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a great answer but I've found *some* tips to hopefully (not guaranteed) increase the speed of your batch files.

> Load Batch Files on to a RAM Drive.   Use a small-size RAM drive with
>   small cluster sizes to preserve memory. Then place the RAM Drive batch
>   directory at or near the start of your path statement. Your batch
>   files will run much faster because they are always in memory. Automate
>   the process by placing statements in your AUTOEXEC.bat to create a RAM
>   drive and then a BATCH directory on that RAM Drive. Next have it copy
>   the batch files to it.
>
> Give Full Path names for all Commands.   This allows DOS to go
>   immediately to the directory required, thus saving a path search. So,
>   as an example, if the MOVE command is to be used, issue it as
>   "C:\DOS\MOVE..." rather than just "MOVE..." .
>
> This method can also be extended to issuing full paths for the files on which actions are to take place. This means that a command
>   will act upon only files on the stated drive and in the stated
>   directory. This is good because if the batch file were to
>   inadvertently be run in a wrong directory, unexpected things might
>
> happen. Unintended files might even be deleted or modified. Directing
>   DOS to the place where you want actions to occur, even if it is still
>   within the current directory, is a wise and safe method.

Unfortunately those are the only tips I could find, and they probably aren't even worth it.

Sorry.

**Source:**
http://www.chebucto.ns.ca/~ak621/DOS/Bat-Tips.html

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Are paragraphs 2 onwards still relevant? It mentions DOS a few times... also, what's the source for this?

Comment: The source seems pretty old (it has that ***musky*** smell). That's why I added the disclaimer "hopefully", because generally modern computers don't care if you use direct paths or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, you can't get reasonable speed change in your case:

- I think, most time your bat-file perform `svnadmin dump`, where you have minimal amount of possibilities to change anything (except testing changing from `--deltas` to incremental|revision-range dumps)
- You can think about changing backup-strategy: use svnsync or backup repositories as *ordinary directories and additional files*